# Android AudioTrack cannot be INITIALIZED

Tags: android

I have a problem with initializing android AudioTrack.  I have Nexus One with android 2.3.3.

Here is my code:

int _rate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);

int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(_rate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

AudioTrack atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                _rate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    buffersize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

if (atrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED)
...

So the state of the atrack is always AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED

The application manifest is

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="BigLeftEarActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

Could you help me?  What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

After line

int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(_rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

I added

buffersize *= 2;

and audio track was initialized.

This is not a perfect solution.  Maybe it would be enough to add just one byte to the buffer, but it works.

"Feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes Feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes."

Comment: I am having the same issue with my Nexus One, I see a log line line that says "minFrameCount 3072, framecount 1536".  However, of course I passed in 3072 as the buffer size... is this a Nexus One bug???

Comment: You may find that this is because "getMinBufferSize returns the minimum size in BYTES. if you are writing that exact same number of SHORTS (which are two bytes each) then you will over-fill the buffer. If you were to write a byte array whose length is that exact number, you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found your issue:

You are using the AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize() for an AudioTrack.  You should use the AudioTrack.getMinBUfferSize() instead, this should give you the appropriate value.

`mAudioRecBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO , AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);`

`mAudioPlayBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO , AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);`